# The operation could not be completed (com.SDK.facebook error 5)

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am posting a image on wall but getting this error .how to solve this error.
The operation could not be completed (com.SDK.facebook error 5)

```
var fb = require('facebook');
 fb.appid = 576786815719384;
 fb.permissions = ['publish_stream'];
 var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('ui/images/a.png');

 var blob = f.read();
var data = {
    message: 'This is a pumpkin',
    picture: blob
};
fb.requestWithGraphPath('photos', data, 'POST', function(e){
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath('photos' ...
```

To:

```
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/photos' ...
```

My code is exactly as yours, and it worked.